# Where is the node_modules folder placed in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I uploaded a folder to Lambda with these contents:

- main.js
- node_modules

The code in `main.js` is executed, but it fails when I try to execute something inside the `node_modules` folder because it cannot find the file (ENOENT). It works locally.

This is what I've tried to locate the `node_modules` folder:

- /var/task/node_modules
- /var/runtime/node_modules
- ./node_modules

This is the command I'm trying to execute from `main.js`:

```
    const { stdout, stderr } = await execa('./node_modules/.bin/prisma', ['migrate', 'deploy'])
```

Note: It is  worth pointing out that I cannot just execute the command directly.

Comment: Did you package your Lambda function and dependencies per the [instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-package.html#nodejs-package-dependencies)?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've run into the same issue trying to run prisma migrations from a lambda.

Comment: Any updates here? I am stuck as well

Comment: I ended up using a kubernetes job. I did make it work with Lambda, but it was an ugly solution. I'll see if I can find it, but triggering stuff from kubernetes ended up being much simpler.